# How do I set up a test cert for an SSL connection in .NET?

Tags: .net

I would like to create an SSL connection for generic TCP communication.  I think I figured out how to do it in the code, using the info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx
What I'm having trouble with is creating a cert so I can test this out.  I tried makecert.exe testCert, and that created a cert, but apparently it doesn't have a private key associated with it.  So what I'm looking for is the simplest procedure to create a cert and get the connection to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a *simple* way to do this yet, but I found [this site](http://www.herongyang.com/crypto/openssl_crt.html) helpful a few months back.

O'Reilly also published a book called Network Security Hacks (available on Safari) that has a section starting at Hack #45 on creating your own certificate authority.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question referencing apache, but someone linked to a microsoft howto on the response. It may be helpful.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-to-use-while-testing-a-web-app)

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else attempting this the pkcs12 certificate created as detailed here [openssl question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440762/openssl-command-line-troubles) and using the X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile method gets past the private key problem. Note I used openssl with cygwin on Windows.